# React/Jest - How to mock the behavior of event.preventDefault and event.stopPropagation

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have an input field as follows:

```
<Input name="score" type="number" className={cx(['input-width'])} value={this.state.score} isIncomplete={false} isInvalid={this.state.isScoreInvalid} min="0" max="100" onKeyPress={this.handleInput} onChange={this.updateValue} onBlur={this.updateScoreInvalidState} />
```

Below function gets called OnKeypress

```
handleInput(event) {
    const charCode = (typeof event.which === 'number') ? event.which : event.keyCode;

    if (charCode === 45 || charCode === 46) {
      console.log("Here-------------");
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
```

Below function gets called onChange

```
updateValue(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}
```

I want to test this behavior:
If invalid input: '-' OR '.'
Ignore the input and do not update state variable score.
Have the following test.

```
it('should render input field correctly with invalid character as input', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowWithIntl(<TestView {...testProps} />).first().shallow();
    const score = wrapper.find('Input[name="score"]');
    const onKeypressEvent = {
      preventDefault: jest.fn(),
      stopPropagation: jest.fn(),
      which: 45,
      target: { name: 'score', value: '-' },
    };
    const onChangeEvent = {
      target: { name: 'score', value: '-' },
    };

    expect(wrapper.state('score')).toEqual(5);
    expect(wrapper.state('isScoreInvalid')).toEqual(false);

    score.simulate('keypress', onKeypressEvent);
    score.simulate('change', onChangeEvent);
    wrapper.update();

    expect(wrapper.state('score')).toEqual(5);
    expect(wrapper.state('isScoreInvalid')).toEqual(false);
  });
```

Test is not working as expected. It is not preventing the event.
[image: Test Output]

How to test this functionality? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
const event = {
    preventDefault: jest.fn(),
    clipboardData: {
      getData: () => pasteValue,
    },
  } as unknown as React.ClipboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>;
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* it answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.

Comment: aint no time to solve his problem but wanted to help him to show how i mocked event, preventDefault and the others in typescript,react but yes u r right